# Autoresizing windows in Kubuntu slow. Frozen screen

Tags: kubuntu, display, resize, tiling

Whenever I try to resize and tile two windows in Kubuntu 18.04, my screen freezes up. Why is this the case?

Switching between two windows is also very slow (with alt tab or otherwise; the entire thing freezes up)

```
inxi -Fxxz
```

```
System:    Host: konsole Kernel: 5.0.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.9 (Qt 5.9.5) dm: sddm,sddm Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A515-51G v: V1.08 serial: N/A
           Mobo: KBL model: Charmander_KL v: V1.08 serial: N/A UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde v: V1.08 date: 06/15/2017
Battery    BAT1: charge: 44.6 Wh 100.0% condition: 44.6/48.9 Wh (91%) volts: 16.8/15.2
           model: COMPAL PABAS0241231 serial: <filter>status: Full
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-8250U (-MT-MCP-) arch: Kaby Lake rev.10 cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 14400
           clock speeds: min/max: 400/3400 MHz 1: 922 MHz 2: 1577 MHz 3: 2085 MHz 4: 1921 MHz 5: 2128 MHz
           6: 2056 MHz 7: 1907 MHz 8: 1896 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:5917
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX150] bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1d10
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.4 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.97hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce MX150/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:9d71
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.0.0-31-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 port: 3000 bus-ID: 02:00.1 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
           IF: enp2s0f1 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
           driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:24fb
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (9.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10SPZX size: 1000.2GB serial: <filter> temp: 42C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 46G used: 27G (62%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
           ID-2: /home size: 865G used: 57G (7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 6.20GB used: 0.02GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      System: supported: N/A
           No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
           Unused Devices: none
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:48C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 238 Uptime: 2:40 Memory: 2105.7/3817.4MB Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201 running in konsole) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: Edited. Can you help with the first issue? Thanks.

Comment: Edited with inxi output.

Comment: I switched to intel on my prime settings, resizing is swift now. But is that a permanent solution? Will I still be able to use my gpu for say gaming? (or other computation? Or does this just affect the display?

Comment: Sorry, no idea!

Comment: does anyone else have any solution?